# Talking with App between Multiple Devices

Tags: android, gps, google-cloud-storage, android-gps

I am developing an app which can be used for sharing location between 2 or more devices. One can be a publisher and other can be a subscriber. I got the first part done where I have an app which can read current lat-long from the device.

The second part is to publish it a repository (which is accessible on the internet to other devices also) so that other devices which subscribed to feeds of this device, will get such values and then render location on their devices. i.e. Bus Sending it location and people can subscribe to it to check when it will come near their home so that they leave office to reach bus stop just before 5 mins left for the bus to arrive at their stops.

I am looking where can be the best place to put such date where many devices can read and write (kind of online cache) for my application.

Comment: I meant 'Sharing Data Feed among Devices (one publisher and many Subscribers)'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/products/realtime-database/). Google Cloud Storage is not a good backend for something like this since it doesn't provide synchronization, and it would be hard to separate and authorize access to this privacy sensitive data.